# Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//li[@id="tablist1-tab3"]"} error using Selenium and Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I have received this error for several times:

```
Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//li[@id="tablist1-tab3"]"}
```

Code that I have used is:

```
options.addArguments("--headless");
options.addArguments("window-size=1200x900");
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
WebElement tab = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@id=\"tablist1-tab3\"]"));
tab.click();
```

Can someone help me with this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("li#tablist1-tab3"))).click();
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//li[@id=\"tablist1-tab3\"]"))).click();
  ```

Answer (score 1):

WebElement tab = driver.findElement(By.xpath('//li[@id="tablist1-tab3"]'));
try this

Comment: You can inspect this element on website and in source code by clicking right mouse click you can copy exact xpath.

Comment: this is the xpath : //*[@id="tablist1-tab3"]. I m at the begin and I had this error for several times.

Comment: WebElement tab = driver.findElement(By.xpath('//*[@id="tablist1-tab3"]'));
I think you missed * sign

Comment: now i have received : SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//*li[@id="tablist1-tab3"]' is not a valid XPath expression.

Comment: in your new xpath tag element <li> is missing :D what I always do, I copy xpath from website and I put it into single quotes..

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="tablist1-tab3"]/span"} . I have copied the correct Xpath and i received the same error

Comment: WebElement tab = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/ul/li[3]"));
       
    tab.click();

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the element is not inside an iFrame. If it is, then you need to first find the iFrame element and use Selenium's switchTo(). After that you will be able to locate elements inside the iframe.